# mysql_fetch array not display correctlly

Tags: php, mysql, database

I trying to load data from mysql db as a default value on e textbox. The problem that im getting is that in the textbox wont appear the complete data just the first Word. For example what it should print on the text box is "'Teatro Romano Sagunt (Calle del Castillo)" and im getting just "Teatro". My code is (ignore the wrong spaces in the label tags i put them cos otherwise that part of the code wasnt vivible in the forum):

< label for="lugar">- Lugar < /label>
        < input name="lugar" type="text" id="lugar")

```
      if (!empty($_POST['modify_id']))
      {
      $id= $_POST['modify_id'];

        if(!($conexion= mysql_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx)))
            {
                echo 'error';
                exit();
            }
        else
            {
                $conexion= mysql_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx');
                mysql_select_db('blabla',$conexion);
                $ssql = "select * from algo WHERE `id` LIKE $id";
                $rs = mysql_query($ssql);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($rs)) 
                {
                    echo 'value='.$row[lugar].' />';
                }

            }
      }
        ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Besides that, your code contains syntax errors and makes not very much sense - for example, why do you connect to your database twice?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is syntax error in your code.

Replace

```
 if(!($conexion= mysql_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx)))
```

With

```
 if(!($conexion= mysql_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx'))) / you for `'` here.
```

Comment: Thanks...this is the code now (working) 

if (!empty($_POST['modify_id']))
    {
    $id= $_POST['modify_id'];

     $conexion= mysql_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx');
     mysql_select_db('blabla',$conexion);
     $ssql = "select * from algo WHERE `id` LIKE $id";
     $rs = mysql_query($ssql);
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($rs)) 
     {
      echo "<label for='lugar'>- Lugar</label>
        <input name='lugar' type='text' id='lugar' value='$row[lugar]' />";
     }
 
    }
    else echo "<label for='lugar'>- Lugar</label>
        <input name=

Answer (score 0):

your echo statement should be like this

```
 echo '<input type="text" name="your_name_val" value="'.$row[lugar].'" />';
```

or you can use like this

```
 $value = $row[lugar];

echo '<input type="text" name="your_name_val" value="'.$value.'" />';
```